# mix use of regular class and ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Want to generate different icons in an `ng-repeat`:

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
<i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
...
```

How can I specify only one of the classes using `ng-class`?

If I wrote:

```
<i class="fa" ng-class="{{t.icon}}"></i>
```

Then the generated output is

```
<i class="fa" ng-class="fa-pencil"></i>
<i class="fa" ng-class="fa-briefcase"></i>
```

and of course the icon does not show on page.

Comment: but what I need is different class for each icon.

Comment: That's because you're misusing `ngClass` ([see the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass)): `<i class="fa" ng-class="t.icon"></i>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use angular expression. This works:

```
<i class="fa" ng-class="t.icon"></i>
```

(See plunker with example on the p tag: http://plnkr.co/edit/AUN81QF0COtYMeedBygJ?p=preview )

You can put various inputs in ngClass, you can see them in:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

The arguments section has a brief description about them.